# How to show individual li-elements on scroll based on window height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I am trying to add a class to my each of my `LI` elements based on how far down the page is scrolled.

If my viewport is `2000px` tall, the first `li` should have add class "`.active`" after `500px`. Then after yet another `500px` scroll down, the second `LI` should have applied class "`active`" and the previous `LI` should have removed the class and so on.

The JavaScript should calculate the pixels based on the height of the viewport because I don't always know how tall the page is.

I know it is possible with jquery and some (each) but I don't know how and where to start. Any help is much appreciated. :-)

```css
.wrapper {
min-height: 2000px;
}
.header {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
background: #eee;
right: 0;
left: 0;
top: 0;
}
ul {
position: relative;
list-style: none;
height: 35px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
li {
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
transition: all .2s ease;
transform: translateY(100%);
line-height: 35px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 20px;
}
li.active {
transform: translateY(0);
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="header">
    <ul class="list">
      <li>I wil lbe visible after a threshold of 500px</li>
      <li class="active">I should be visible when user has scrolled (pageheight - 500px / 4)</li>
      <li>I should be visible when user has scrolled (pageheight - 500px / 4) * 2 </li>
      <li>I should be visible when user has scrolled (pageheight - 500px / 4) * 3 </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I made this little example to demonstrate the markup:
https://jsfiddle.net/a1hq5tg3/2/

Comment: You forgot to include the JS you've attempted yourself

Comment: Do you mean something like this (see demo): http://callmenick.com/post/single-page-site-with-smooth-scrolling-highlighted-link-and-fixed-navigation

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No I need the JS. I haven't got a clue how to code it actually :-)

Comment: @Victor Yes, but I need it to toggle the class names based on scroll amount  and not on divs that become visible as you scroll. So not quite the same :)

Comment: Can you use percentages? If you can this might work for ya: https://jsfiddle.net/wdwb3uh3/6/

Comment: or you might want to look at this: http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints - should be what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can use native browser event to check current scroll position to update required "li" based on scroll range

```
window.onscroll = function(args) {
   console.log(document.body.scrollTop);

   if(document.body.scrollTop > 200 && document.body.scrollTop < 300) {
      document.getElementsByClassName('active')[0].className.replace('active', '');
      document.getElementsByTagName('li')[next].className += ' active';
   }
};
```

Comment: Thnaks for your answer. No it doesn't do what I want. I want it to calculate the height of the page and the show the LI's as you scroll. (I'm not really an js expert) :(

Comment: Why not? This event fires each time you scroll your document. So you can select ranges when element should be shown or hidden.

if(pos > 0 && pos < 10) show el1
else if(pos >=10 && pos <20) show el2
else if ...

Comment: Maybe its just my coding skills. Can you make it work in my jsfiddle example? Im not very skilled in JS

Comment: @VadimB Fiddle looks good to me. Only issue is that the OP said the page hight wouldn't always be 2000px - if you merge your + my fiddle. This should work: https://jsfiddle.net/wdwb3uh3/9/

Answer (score 0):

My answer as a result of @VadimB and my comments / answers.

```
$(window).on('scroll', function() {

  var windowSize = $(window).scrollTop(),
    documentSize = $(document).height() - $(window).height();

  $('li').removeClass('hello');

  if (windowSize < (documentSize) * 0.25) {
    $('li').removeClass('hello');
  } else if (windowSize < (documentSize) * 0.50) {
    $('li:nth-child(2)').addClass('hello');
  } else if (windowSize < (documentSize) * 0.75) {
    $('li:nth-child(3)').addClass('hello');
  } else if (windowSize > (documentSize) * 0.75) {
    $('li:nth-child(4)').addClass('hello');
  }

});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/randomobject/43sspmL5/